# Why is the updated[value] = [] giving me TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'?

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def build_province_attraction_dict(dic):
    updatedic = {}
    for value in dic.values():
    
        for key,value1 in dic.items():
            updatedic[value] = []
            if value1 == value:
                updatedic[value].append(key)
    return updatedic
```

I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: LInked to dupe, but tl;dr is that you can't use a list as a dict key because a list can be changed, which would invalidate the key.  The easiest workaround is to convert the list to a tuple, which makes it immutable, but if you're trying to use a list as a key in the first place you might have some deeper problem.

Comment: Your code would work as long as the parameter `dic` is not of the form `{'k1': ['i1']}`.  If any of the values in `dic` are a list then `updatedic[value]` is the equivalent of executing something like this: `updatedic[['a', 'b', 'c']] = []`.